# Is this differentiation under the integral justified by Leibniz rule?

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I am trying to understand the following proof from Hunter's "Applied Analysis":
[image]

[image]

I was wondering why we need to bring up the dominated convergence theorem to justify differentiation under the integral. We have $\varphi$ is an element of the Schwarz space which is infinitely differentiable so we just use the Leibniz rule to justify this right?

Edit: This is the theorem for differentiating under integral
[image]

Comment: $\varphi$ is Schwartz, so DCT is applicable (be sure you can justify this, i.e fill in the details provided by the text), but it's not just because $\varphi$ is infinitely differentiable. You need to use extra information about boundedness.

Comment: Give us a precise quote of the version of the Leibniz rule you have in mind. (Seems to me the trivial versions are usually referring to $\int_a^b$, hence do not apply here)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich doesn't the leibniz rule just say that we only need continuously differentiable functions? Then we can differentiate under the integral sign: https://brilliant.org/wiki/differentiate-through-the-integral/

Comment: We need a **complete** statement of the theorem! "We can differentiate under the integral sign" doesn't explain what you're talking about. Look it up! See, the reason it doesn't apply here is because of the _details_ in the hypotheses. So nobody can explain why it doesn't apply until you tell us those details. (We can't supply the details ourselves because the details vary from book to book...)

Comment: @peek-a-boo hi, i have made an edit and posted the theorem of differentiating under integral. We just need to make some adjustments, instead of $X \times I$ we have $R^n \times R^n$ and $f(x,k)= e^{-ikx} \varphi(x)$ and due to the fact that $\varphi(x)$ is in the Schwarz space, we have the bound $\frac{C}{1+|x|^N}$ for some  N which is integrable and is our dominating function.